# Frame by frame video processing on android

Tags: android, video, video-processing

I need my app to do following:

- Grab frame
- Draw some elements on top of the frame (these elements are not static)
- Save the frame to the other video

Video is read from and stored to SD card. Audio should remain unchanged. Quality, resolution, FPS, etc should remain the same.

What is the best solution to do this? 
Can this be done with MediaCodec (I need my app to run on at least API14, ideally at API10)?